# Adjective for something pertaining to one’s values

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the adjective word that means “*pertaining to one’s values*”

The word I’m looking for would be analogous to the way the word ‘*emotional*’ pertains to one’s emotions.

As in: “We are looking for creative and [*adjective pertaining to one’s values*] alignment in our group.”

I’m aware of words like ‘*moral*’ and ‘*ethical*,’ I’m just wondering if there is a derivation specifically for this use of the word ‘*value*’ as I think there are subtle but meaningful differences between them.

Comment: If you are referring to political, cultural values the term identitarian  may fit. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/identitarian

Comment: ... That's more 'promoting one’s group's values', Gio.

Comment: This looks like a lexical gap. 'Valuary' exists, but it's a given name.

Comment: Wouldn't _moral_ or _ethical_ work in this context? IOW, what could _moral alignment_ mean other than _alignment in terms of values_?

Comment: On the face of it, I'd agree with @m.a.a. : values are the content of ethics and morality. But in your example -- and I'm sorry if this is a bit blunt -- you may be looking for 'ideological'

Comment: What kinds of values are you talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about adherence to company values (e.g. putting the customer first,  prioritizing shareholder returns, etc.)?

Comment: Use of *and* as a conjunction may be blocking alternative phrasing, e.g., *We are looking for conformally creative alignment with our group.”

Comment: I'd say: personal conviction

Comment: @JCruz:  What is "alignment"?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Barmar's line of thought in a comment above, the compound adjective **value-centric** might work in some situations:

> We are looking for creative and **value-centric** alignment in our group.

> **-centric** (combining form)
>
> Forming adjectives with the sense 'having a centre of a specified
> type', as **polycentric** *adj*., **ethnocentric** *adj*.,
> **Eurocentric** *adj*., **heliocentric** *adj*., **technocentric** *adj*., etc. [OED]

---

> PAs [Physician Assistants] are ultimately related to value, dollars,
> and needs. Business journals define value as the return related to the
> investment cost. Values in philosophy are standards or ideals with
> which to evaluate actions, people, things, or situations. Beauty,
> honesty, justice, peace, and generosity are all examples of values
> that many people endorse. The essence of economics is the three
> underlying principles of scarcity, efficiency, and sovereignty. The
> medical concept of value reflects needs, wishes, preferences, and the
> ethics of providine **value-centric** patient care.
> [Sharona Kanosfsy;
> *Intrinsic Skills for Physician Assistants*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Intrinsic_Skills_for_Physician_Assistant/QFvBDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22value-centric%22%20definition&pg=PA80&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> The goal of **value-centric** selling is to keep the consumer in mind
> at every stage of the sales process ["What do you mean by Value
> Centric Selling?"; tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-do-you-mean-by-value-centric-selling)

> **Value-Centric** Analysis is an advanced form of system concept analysis that uses a system value model to measure the relative
> attractiveness of alternative architectures, materiel solutions, and
> conceptual system designs. **Value-Centric** Design is a systems
> engineering process in which design alternatives are evaluated by a
> value model, and the highest value alternative is generally chosen.
> ["Value-Centric Analysis and Value-Centric
> Design"; ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228463959_Value-Centric_Analysis_and_Value-Centric_Design) (2010)

[Charles Kerns; ***Value-Centered** Ethics: A Proactive System to Shape Ethical Behavor*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Value_centered_Ethics/PLjuFrOyy-oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20word%20value-centric&pg=PR12&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

Answer (score 0):

"Evaluative" works for me.  “We are looking for creative and evaluative alignment in our group.” From the [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/evaluative):

evaluative (ɪˈvæljʊətɪv), adj

1. of, denoting, or based on an act of evaluating
2. philosophy expressing an attitude or value judgment; emotive

Comment: Don't use screenshots of text; instead copy and paste the text into your answer directly. This is necessary so that everyone can read it, even people who use screen-readers.

Comment: @Laurel: Thanks. Will do. Don

Comment: No; 'evaluative' strongly defaults to 'regarding the valuation of' not 'pertaining to one's values'.